# put dataTable elements in bootstrap columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm trying to implement a bootstrap data-table, it's working fine but I can't fix it's layout. I want to put the `dataTables_info` and `dataTables_paginate` in a `col-xs-6`, because each one of them is in a separate line and I want them both to appear in the same line. How can I do that? Here is a photo of my problem:

[image: Data-table info and paginate]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the `col-xs-6` inside a `div` with class `row`.
Example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: dataTables_info and dataTables_paginate are rendered from somewhere they don't have divs in the html code